# Read contents in a line in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, read

I have a file with contents in this order which is separated by space

```
  4096 1230 4560 1024.... n
```

How can i read each number and pass it on to another command, eg divide each number by 1024.

Answer (score 3):

While tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) the simplest is to `read` it into an array:

```
bash-4.1$ read -a l < file
```

Then you can iterate over the values like this:

```
bash-4.1$ for n in "${l[@]}"; do echo "$n / 1024 ≈ $((n/1024)) = $(bc -l<<<"$n/1024")"; done
4096 / 1024 ≈ 4 = 4.00000000000000000000
1230 / 1024 ≈ 1 = 1.20117187500000000000
4560 / 1024 ≈ 4 = 4.45312500000000000000
1024 / 1024 ≈ 1 = 1.00000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as the data is space delimited you can load the contents of the file into an array like so:

```
arr=$(< data.txt)
```

Once the data's been loaded into the array, `$arr` you can then use a `for` loop to go through it, and perform your division by 1024.

```
$ for num in ${arr[*]}; do 
    res=$( expr $num / 1024 )
    echo "$num / 1024 = $res"
  done
```

#### Example

```
$ for num in ${arr[*]}; do res=$( expr $num / 1024 ); echo "$num / 1024 = $res";done
4096 / 1024 = 4
1230 / 1024 = 1
4560 / 1024 = 4
1024 / 1024 = 1
```

If you'd like to get floating point results as opposed to integers you can use `bc` to do this instead:

```
$ for num in ${arr[*]}; do 
    res=$(echo "scale=2; $num/1024" |bc)
    echo "$num / 1024 = $res"
  done
4096 / 1024 = 4.00
1230 / 1024 = 1.20
4560 / 1024 = 4.45
1024 / 1024 = 1.00
```

You can control the number of decimal places by changing the value passed to `scale=`. Setting `` `scale=5 ``:

```
4096 / 1024 = 4.00000
1230 / 1024 = 1.20117
4560 / 1024 = 4.45312
1024 / 1024 = 1.00000
```

#### References

- [Performing Math calculation in Bash](https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/)

Answer (score 2):

The gist of shell scripting is to run as few commands as possible. Here, `awk` is typically the command that is best designed to split lines into fields and do arithmetics:

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i<= NF; i++) $i = $i/1024; print}' < your-file
```

Using shell loops in shells is often a sign of bad shell scripting practice.

Comment: Shell loops is bad practice? Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

For this simple arithmetic task, you can stick to shell built-in constructs and [call `read`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99577) to read and split the first line or [use command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100594) to read the input and split it.

Alternatively, you can treat this as a text processing problem and [call `awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100608) to do the whole processing.

If your actual task requires passing each number to a separate command, you can use `xargs`. `xargs` has a weird input format but if your input has none of `\'"` you don't need to worry about that.

```
<input.txt xargs -n1 somecommand
```

Answer (score -2):

For large lists I usually build a counter to tear off one line at a time, then whatever variable operation you want to perform can be done reliably.. I've had large arrays (for line in `cat foo.bar`; do ) go to pieces ..To wit:

```
InCt=`cat foo.bar|wc -l`
RunCt=1
while [ $InCt -ge $RunCt ]; do
  LINE=`head -${RunCt} foo.bar|tail -1`

  # do whatever you need with the line

let RunCt="$RunCt +1"
done
```

Comment: Ouch. UUOC, missing quotes, 4 commands run, 1 pipe and 1 command substitution for each line in the file, file read from the start at each iteration. Come on...

Comment: Calling `head` and `tail` once per line needlessly precludes non-seekable input (e.g. a pipe), and is very slow for medium to large files.